# Checkbox alignment on logout page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, logout

On the [logout page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout), the checkbox is mis-aligned.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: A simple fix, remove the bottom margin from `#logout-form #everywhere`. If only this question had some freehand circles...

Comment: This is by design, in order to prevent OCD users from logging out.

Comment: Huh ? Don't SE employees have access to some sort of internal bug tracker ? It seems kinda strange to me that an SE employee reports a bug on Meta..

Comment: @JonasCz We use trello boards for some additional triage/tracking on some projects, but beyond that we don't feel the need to report bugs in multiple places... so meta wins. As a bonus, if a user notices the same issue, they can see that it's already been reported.

Comment: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JCK79.jpg)

Comment: @Will I'm feeling bad now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Kurtis, this has been fixed.